# Slick JS gutters or spaces between carousel items

Tags: javascript, slick.js

How do you put gutters or spaces between carousel items in slick.js. Below is my js and html, and there are no spaces between the slider images or items.

```
 $('.responsive').slick({
     slidesToShow: 4,
     slidesToScroll: 4,
     responsive: [
     {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
     }
     },
    ]
    });


<div class="responsive">
  <div> <img src="slide1.jpeg"></div>
  <div> <img src="slide2.jpeg"></div>
  <div> <img src="slide3.jpeg"></div>
  <div> <img src="slide4.jpeg"></div>
  <div> <img src="slide5.jpeg"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a plugin option to define this through Slick itself. Here's a CodePen Slick.js carousel example, you'll see the carousel spacing is defined through the CSS via the `margin` and `padding` attributes (in this case via the `<h3>` tags). http://codepen.io/saviaga/pen/qdENOx

css:

```
.responsive div img{ 
    margin: 10px;
}
```